# How to install a deprecated version of uws

Tags: node.js, npm, discord.js, npm-install

I know that theres a latest version on github (websocket.js) by the same author, but I specifically need a version that works with **discord.js**. I tried installing a usable version, with

```
npm install uws@10.148.1
```

but it doesn't work, it returns this error:

```
npm ERR! ELOOP: too many symbolic links encountered
```

I'm also not too sure which versions I should install, as I just started using discord.js.

**My questions:**

Firstly,

**Is there a uws version compatible with discord.js** that I can install, and how could I install it?

And if not:

**Is there a way** to fix this eloop error?

Any help would be appreciated? If I'm not clear, please drop a comment below and I'll try to clarify. Once again, thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will refer you to these other posts for some detailed information on the subject.

This one involves the error you're referring to so it might be an answer to your problem.
[ELOOP Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63193051/eloop-too-many-symbolic-links-encountered)

This one involves some good information on how to use npm in different ways that may be useful.
[npm outdated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36329944/how-to-determine-path-to-deep-outdated-deprecated-packages-npm)

I looked up the package and created a test folder to see if I could install the package you're talking about in there using `npm i outdated uws@10.148.1`.

I then uninstalled it using `npm uninstall outdated uws@10.148.1`

Everything seemed to work fine besides all the deprication errors and warnings.

Comment: Thanks! What was missing from my command was "outdated".